# PHP extension quicker way to get the _GET variable in C

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I use this code to get the $_GET variable in C

```
zend_array *symbol_table;
zval *_GET = zend_hash_find_ind(&EG(symbol_table), zend_string_init("_GET", sizeof("_GET") - 1, 0));
```

The question is why did the PHP store the "_GET" data to a specific variable, and in the C we use that variable instead to find them from &EG(symbol_table) with the function zend_hash_find_ind, if it finds from a hash, the performance might be impacted, right?

Same for get the element value from the _GET array

```
char *value = Z_STRVAL_P(zend_hash_str_find(Z_ARRVAL_P(_GET), "baz", sizeof("baz") - 1));
```

In the PHP or other languages, we can get directly the element by the index likes $_GET['baz'], so I think it can read directly the value in the "baz" memory address. From the code above, it uses the function zend_hash_str_find, that mean the program must to loop through the list to find the value, the performance again might be impacted, right?

Comment: php arrays are hashmaps, getting data via key from hashmap is aggregated O(1), so your assumptions are wrong

Comment: Hi @IłyaBursov so the zend_hash_find_ind is O(1), right? same for zend_hash_str_find?

Comment: yes, both are essentially the same, and their performance should be O(1) on average

Comment: last time I touched php extensions - was around 2009, so I'm not an expert

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247402/discussion-between-mark-smith-and-ilya-bursov).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a quicker way to access the `_GET` variable when writing a PHP extension. You have to keep in mind that the PHP engine is responsible for taking the raw HTTP request information from the SAPI and parsing it into the expected representation for access in PHP userspace (e.g. via superglobal variables such as `_GET` and `_SERVER`). You could access the low-level SAPI parameters, but they won't include, for example, a parsed and decoded query string.

Another thing to keep in mind is that the superglobal variables are autoloaded at first access. (These variables are also called "auto globals" for this reason.) In userspace, this is a transparent process; however, in writing a low-level PHP extension, you must ensure the superglobal variable has been loaded (i.e. "armed"). If your extension code runs before first userspace access of an auto global variable, then the variable will not exist. Here's an example of how to check an auto global variable and arm it if it does not exist:

```c
zend_bool check_global(const char* gbl,size_t gbllen)
{
    zval* entry;

    /* Make sure superglobal is auto-loaded already. */
    if (!zend_hash_str_exists(&EG(symbol_table),gbl,gbllen)) {
        entry = zend_hash_str_find(CG(auto_globals),gbl,gbllen);

        if (entry == NULL) {
            return FAILURE;
        }

        zend_auto_global* ag = Z_PTR_P(entry);
        ag->armed = ag->auto_global_callback(ag->name);
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}

// Example usage:
zend_bool result = check_global("_GET",sizeof("_GET")-1);
```

And here's an example function for looking up the value from an auto global variable:

```c
zval* get_global(const char* gbl,size_t gbllen,const char* key,size_t keylen)
{
    zval* entry;
    HashTable* bucket;

    if (check_global(gbl,gbllen) != SUCCESS) {
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Lookup element and return as string zval. */
    entry = zend_hash_str_find(&EG(symbol_table),gbl,gbllen);
    if (entry == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    bucket = Z_ARRVAL_P(entry);
    entry = zend_hash_str_find(bucket,key,keylen);

    return entry;
}

// Example usage:
zval* zSessId = get_global("_COOKIE",sizeof("_COOKIE")-1,"SESSID",sizeof("SESSID")-1);
zval* zParam = get_global("_GET",sizeof("_GET")-1,"baz",sizeof("baz")-1);
```

For even more convenience, you can create a macro like so:

```c
/* Arguments to this macro should be string literals. */
#define GET_GLOBAL(g,e)                         \
    get_global(g,sizeof(g)-1,e,sizeof(e)-1)
```